# R issue: Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) -- no such table

Tags: r

I am trying to query a dataframe with sqldf in R.

The dataframe exists but sqldf can't seem tof ind it.

Here is the dataframe...

```
> head(pred,3)
  0   1
1 4.3 .234
2 6.5 .111
3 7.5 .917
```

But when I query it with sqldf, I get the following error:

```
> a <- sqldf("select * from pred  limit 6")
Loading required package: tcltk
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such table: pred)
```

It seems like sqldf can't find the pred table. Why might that be? How can I query it with sqldf?

Comment: When I try to reproduce this it works for me.  One possibility is that `pred` is not a data frame.  sqldf looks for data frames so if it were a zoo object or a matrix or any other object which is not a data frame then it would not find it.  Try `class(pred)`.

Comment: Perhaps `pred` is not a `data.frame`?  Try `class(pred)`. If `pred` is a matrix then `pred_dt <- as.data.frame(pred)` will create a data frame so that you have something that `sqldf` will recognize.

Answer (score 8):

Install RH2 package and run 
**require(RH2)** 
before running your sqldf query. The problem should be fixed.

Comment: Any idea why RH2 isn't a required package?